# apt-get has a error

Tags: installation, upgrade, apt, kernel, update-manager

when I use:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get this Error:

```
E: Could not open file /var/lib/dpkg/status - open (2: No such file or directory)

E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

i use : `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

and I get this:

```
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/status' for reading: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please read the contents of the file /var/lib/dpkg/status using command in terminal "sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status"

Comment: no, it doesn't help me.

Comment: nothing, i think, i remove my status

Comment: Did you see the link @Jai posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following commands step by step.

```
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status

sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial 

sudo dpkg --clear-avail
```

Now  try to

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```